# How to combine observational and experimental data?

Tags: predictive-models, observational-study, random-allocation, forecast-combination

I’m trying to figure out the effects of system changes on user long-term revenue (over a 12-month period, say) for an online platform.

I have a lot of observational data, so I fitted a model that predicts future long-term revenue as a function of user characteristics (age, gender, country, etc.) and actions over two weeks (clicks on ads, clicks on non-ads, time spent on platform etc.). This had a pretty good fit to data.

I ran an experiment to intervene in the system (increase the number of ads shown to users, e.g.). The experiment’s results were very different to predictions from the observational model. The experimental data shows “Increasing the number of ads shown to users in first 2 weeks of the experiment by 1% decreases long-term revenue by 0.5%” (fictitious numbers and relationship).

Now, I want to evaluate another experiment. Let’s say this increases ads shown to users in the first 2 weeks overall by 3%, so our overall experimental data would predict it decreases LT revenue by 1.5%.

But say the % increase is very different across different population subgroups - maybe it’s just 1% in US (with high projected revenue from observational model), and 5% outside US. Is there any way to use the observational predictions to get a better prediction of the effect of the experiment?

I am thinking of something like:

- Run the observational model to get predicted revenue / user
- Weight predicted changes in revenue (from experimental data) by the observational model to get an overall prediction.

Is there a legitimate way to do this?

Comment: Less is more: the point of experimental data is that it's not contaminated by the issues surrounding observational data.

Comment: Also, good predictive power and good causal inference are not the same thing. I think you're confusing these different goals. If your goal is predictive, stick to observational data. The best methods for prediction (ML) are causal black boxes.